# Bidirectional content syncing between google spreadsheets

Tags: database-design, synchronization, google-sheets, dashboard, database-mirroring

I am creating a google spreadsheet dashboard to summarize content from many different projects.  All project content is contained in other google spreadsheets.  For each project there is a task list/to-do list.  I am trying to find a solution that will allow me to do the following:

**1)** Pull task lists from each project spreadsheet into one master task sheet on the dashboard

**2)** Add/edit/delete tasks on the project task sheets, which will then automatically update the master task sheet.

**3)** Add/edit/delete tasks on the master task sheet, which will then automatically update the project task sheets.

Numbers 1 and 2 are fairly simple using the importrange() and query() functions but to my knowledge these are only unidirectional solutions.  Any help with number 3?

Sample Documents:

**[Project 1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmPYYdOO5yOsdHhPRmxkbGdiN1ZsNzdCUmV3c2VrNnc#gid=0)**

**[Project 2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmPYYdOO5yOsdG1tYXlOY2RoMEVSdXIzS0wxTGtCb3c#gid=0)**

**[Dashboard](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmPYYdOO5yOsdGw4YVdFb2J0SWpOOF9vZ3hRRHJLdGc#gid=0)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script and perform the task. But This works in the same spreadsheet. I have not been able to link this with two different spreadsheets.

```
function onEdit()

{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var activeSheetName = ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();

  if( activeSheetName == "Sheet1" || activeSheetName == "Sheet2" )
  {
    var activeCell = activeSheet.getActiveCell();
    var activeCellinA1 = activeCell.getA1Notation();

    if( activeCellinA1 == "A1" )
    {
      var activeCellValue = activeCell.getValue();
      if( activeSheetName == "Sheet1" )
        ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange("A1").setValue(activeCellValue);
      if( activeSheetName == "Sheet2" )
        ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("A1").setValue(activeCellValue);
    }      
  }
}
```